# Fluent NHIbernate Freezes much

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

According to profiler it takes 24 sec for `FluentConfiguration.BuildConfiguration` to complete. Here's the code I use to get Configuration:

```
    MsSqlConfiguration persistenceConfigurer = MsSqlConfiguration
         .MsSql2005
         .ConnectionString(connectionStringBuilder => connectionStringBuilder
                                                      .Server(server)
                                                      .Database(database)
                                                      .Username(userName)
                                                      .Password(password))
         .ProxyFactoryFactory<ProxyFactoryFactory>()
         .CurrentSessionContext<ThreadStaticSessionContext>()
         .DoNot.ShowSql();

FluentConfiguration cfg = Fluently.Configure()
   .Database(persistenceConfigurer)
   .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<ExecutorMap>());

return cfg.BuildConfiguration();
```

The number of map-files is 19. Is it common for Fluent NHibernate to work so long? Might it be my fault? What could be wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is someone else is interested in that issue, it might be useful to read http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2007/10/26/Real-World-NHibernate-Reducing-startup-times-for-large-amount-of.aspx and http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/03/13/an-improvement-on-sessionfactory-initialization.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a profiler, you should be able to see what calls inside of `BuildConfiguration` are taking up that time. What are they?

Assembly scanning would be my guess. Is the assembly that contains your mappings especially large? You've told Fluent NHibernate to scan your assembly for mappings, so regardless of how few mappings there are it still has to scan the entire assembly for them.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be assembly scan. The most time-consuming function inside BuildConfiguration is AddDocument (LoadMappingDocument + AddDocumentThroughQueue). The assembly isn't large. It contains only mappings and implementation of repositories (~ 35 classes).

Comment: `AddDocument` is an NHibernate function, and it's called only when Fluent NHibernate has finished compiling the mappings. How many times is `AddDocument` called? I would expect either once or 19 times, depending on your setup.

Comment: You are right. It's an NHibernate fuction. It's called 19 times.